# My Python Temperature Converter is not working

Tags: python

I tried to make a Temperature Converter but it doesn't work for some reason, here's my code

```
def getinput():
    print("Enter the temperature")
    a = float(input())
def Converter():
    print("Press 1 for Fahrenheit to Celsius\nPress 2 for Celsius to Fahrenheit")
    x = int(input())
    if x == 1:
       a = getinput()
       return (a - 32) * 5/9
    if x == 2:
        a = getinput()
        return (a + 32) * 9/5

Converter()
```

Comment: getinput() doesn't return anything

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: In short, I don't get an answer from the program after entering the temperature

Comment: And in more descriptive sentences? what does it do? what have you tried/researched?

Comment: As @Patrick mentioned,  ```getinput()``` returns nothing (or None), so you're going to get some errors..   along the lines of ```TypeError: unsupported operad type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'```

Comment: Also at no point in the code is anything printed to the console

Comment: I've looked it up in Google but didn't find an answer, I've tried changing Converter to Converter(a) and Converter(getinput), but if I do that, I get a Traceback and a TypeError, TypeError: Converter() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two issues here, the first being that `getinput()` returns nothing which causes the error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

The second issue is that the code does not print the result, you can either print the result from within the function or call print on the function call like so

```
def getinput():
    print("Enter the temperature")
    a = float(input())
    return a
def Converter():
    print("Press 1 for Fahrenheit to Celsius\nPress 2 for Celsius to Fahrenheit")
    x = int(input())
    if x == 1:
       a = getinput()
       return (a - 32) * 5/9
    if x == 2:
        a = getinput()
        return (a + 32) * 9/5

print(Converter())
```

example output:

```
Press 1 for Fahrenheit to Celsius
Press 2 for Celsius to Fahrenheit

1
Enter the temperature

23
-5.0
```

as a small point to note `input()` takes a message as an argument

```
def getinput():
    return float(input("Enter the temperature: "))
def Converter():
    x = int(input("Press 1 for Fahrenheit to Celsius\nPress 2 for Celsius to Fahrenheit\n"))
    if x == 1:
       a = getinput()
       return (a - 32) * 5/9
    if x == 2:
        a = getinput()
        return (a + 32) * 9/5

print(Converter())
```

now `getinput()` is fairly redundant

```
def Converter():
    x = int(input("Press 1 for Fahrenheit to Celsius\nPress 2 for Celsius to Fahrenheit\n"))
    if x == 1:
       a = float(input("Enter the temperature: "))
       return (a - 32) * 5/9
    if x == 2:
        a = float(input("Enter the temperature: "))
        return (a + 32) * 9/5

print(Converter())
```